# jquery ajax post method giving internal server error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

```
 $("[id$=_btnPostReminder]").click(function(){
     var a = $find("<%=Editor1.ClientID%>");
     var remindertext = a.get_content();
     var re=$("#<%=hiddReminderTicketId.ClientID%>").text();
     var res= $("#<%=txtReminderon.ClientID%>").val();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AllTickets.aspx/btnPostReminder",
        data: '{TicketId: ' + re + ',remindertext: ' +  remindertext  + ',reminderon: ' +  res  + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success:
        function Ret(response) { 
        var Result=response.d
        alert(Result)
        $("#<%=txtReminderon.ClientID%>").val("")
        $('#<%=hiddReminderTicketId.ClientID %>').text("")
        $('#<%=lblAlert.ClientID %>').text("Set Successfully");
        return false;
        },
        error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {                        
        alert(jqXHR);
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

C# code behind :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string btnPostReminder(Int64 TicketId, string remindertext, string reminderon)
{
    Common objCommon = new Common();
    DAL objDal = new DAL();
    SqlParameter[] para = new SqlParameter[4];
    para[0] = new SqlParameter("@ticketid", DbType.Int64);
    para[0].Value = TicketId;
    para[1] = new SqlParameter("@REMINDERTEXT", DbType.String);
    para[1].Value = remindertext;
    para[2] = new SqlParameter("@REMINDERON", DbType.DateTime);
    para[2].Value = objCommon.ReturnDate(reminderon);
    para[3] = new SqlParameter("@CREATEDBY", DbType.Int64);
    para[3].Value = Convert.ToInt64(1);

    objDal.ExecuteSP("CREATE_REMINDER", para);

    return   " successfully";
}
```

Comment: Not nearly enough information provided here.

Comment: Thanks for reply, When i click the button it should call the ajax post method but after executing alert method show internal server error

Comment: debug through and see where do you get the error

Comment: Sorry iam new to jquery, i don't know how to debug webmethod. bcoz breakpoint is not working

Comment: Please review http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist for what makes a good question, you need to show that you understand what should happen and give some detail as to what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Found your problem, you are passing `Int64` as parameter which should be string otherwise so when changing it to below I get success message :

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
 public static string btnPostReminder(string TicketId, string remindertext, string reminderon)
    {
        return " successfully";
    }
```

Also your data should look like below:

```
 data: '{"TicketId":"' + re + '","remindertext":"' + remindertext + '","reminderon":"' + res + '"}',
```

Pass as string for parameter and to `TryParse` to see if it is of type `int`.

Comment: Its working Very Very Thanks to all...